# Python: How to add a string at the starting of a counter

Tags: python

I am trying to add a string in for loop only for once. I have added the code and the output. And also added my expected output.

Here is My Code:

```
def divisor() :
    limit = int(input(''))

    for number in range(limit) :
        i = 1
        number = int(input(''))
        terminator = number
        count = 0

        while( terminator > 0 ):
            count = count + 1
            terminator = terminator // 10

        if(count <= 100):
            while i <= number :
                if (number % i == 0):
                    print(i, end=' ', flush=True)
                i = i + 1
            print('')
        else:
            break

divisor()
```

Current Input and Output:

```
Input: 3 (How many input to take)
Input: 6
Output: 1 2 3 6
Input: 15
Output: 1 3 5 15
Input: 23
Output: 1 23
```

I want something like the following:

```
Input: 3 (How many input to take)
Input: 6
Output: Case 1: 1 2 3 6
Input: 15
Output: Case 2: 1 3 5 15
Input: 23
Output: Case 3: 1 23
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do a couple of things.

Don't update the variable number in the loop. Instead, use a new variable so that you can keep track of the iteration number.

Inside the if statement, add a print statement to print "Case" number

```
print ('Case',num+1,':', end = '')
```

Complete code is as follows,

```
def divisor() :
    limit = int(input(''))

    for num in range(limit) :
        i = 1
        number = int(input(''))
        terminator = number
        count = 0

        while( terminator > 0 ):
            count = count + 1
            terminator = terminator // 10

        if(count <= 100):
            print ('Case',num+1,':', end = '')
            while i <= number :
                if (number % i == 0):
                    print(i, end=' ', flush=True)
                i = i + 1
            print('')
        else:
            break

divisor()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `format` or f-string. For example:

```py
i = 3

info = 'case {}'.format(i)
print(info)
>>>'case 3'
# or

info = f'case {i}'
print(info)
>>>'case 3'
```